# How could I define a type here?

Tags: ruby

I have 2 classes like below:

```rb
class Client
  attr_accessor :name, :surname
  
  def initialize(name, surname, code)
    @name = name
    @surname = surname
    @code = code
  end
end

class Account
  attr_accessor :holder, :limit, :total, :number

  def initialize(holder, limit, total, number)
    @number = number
    @holder = holder
    @total = total
    @number = number      
  end
end
```

How could I make the attribute holder of Account to be a Client?

Comment: You shouldn't do this, it's antithetical to Ruby and [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). Ruby purposefully does not have type checking for arguments. Trying to add it back in is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this creating an object Client? I just don't know how

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but generally you should allow any value to be assigned to `holder` so long as it responds to the methods you intend to invoke on it.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this:                                                                                                              it "holder should be a Client" do
    account = Account.new('Rick Diaz', 600, 2000,  '3333-2')

    expect(account.holder).to be_a(Client)
  end

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure `holder` is a instance of `Client`, you can use a `guard` statement.When it doesn't meet your needs, then raise error!

```rb
class Account
  attr_accessor :holder, :limit, :total, :number


  def initialize(holder, limit, total, number)
    raise ArgumentError, 'holder should be a Client' unless holder.is_a?(Client)

    @number = number
    @holder = holder
    @total = total
    @number = number      
  end
 
end
```

Comment: Specifically, it should be an [ArgumentError](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/ArgumentError.html). `raise ArgumentError, 'holder should be a Client' unless holder.is_a?(Client)`

Comment: `ArgumentError` is the catch-all class for any argument validation errors. In this case, a [`TypeError`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/TypeError.html) is more specific.